# xampp for window path reference issue

Tags: apache, xampp

I had to reformat and reinstall XP a while ago which works just dandy.

My issue is that I never re-installed xampp until today (newest version). Going to "localhost/project" works fine. I can see the site but css and images aren't working. Localhost is reading my "/" path references inside the project folders as root "htdocs".

For those who will mention it: I removed the "/" in my php files and the links and reference to styles worked fine, but within the css files, any "../" reference failed.

I think there was a reason for the preceeding "/", but I have since forgotten.

Any have any ideas? None on my searches turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

did you copy your old xampp installation into the same path on your new XP? if not, you have to change the httpd.conf perhaps as apache uses some variables in there to calculate relative paths.

you could also try to use opera dragonfly or another debugger to see errors in your browser

Comment: Thanks for responding.  After I installed the new version of xampp (in the same location that the old version was), I copied the old project and db files to the same folder so that they map out as they did previously.  The site loads, but like I said, it's unstyled, images don't show, and links that start with "/" look to "htdocs instead of the project folder as the root.